# XSLT2.0 How do I stop processing in for-each when my condition is met ? I want to stop processing when first "DirtyFlag"='Y' is processed

Tags: loops, xslt, break

`enter code here`I have this code. I want to stop processing when `DirtyFlag='Y'` is met. I don't want to loop through the rest of the DirtyFlags. `cust:CommunicationProfile` and `cust:CommunicationProfilePreferences` are unbounded, so there could be more than one instance of them and `EUID`, `divisionNumber` and `storeNumber`, but I just want one in the output.

```
<HeaderInformation>
    <xsl:if test="cust:ProcessingInformation[@cust:DirtyFlag='Y']">
        <xsl:for-each select="cust:UpdateTrackingInformation">
            <EUID>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="cust:UpdateUserID != '' ">
                        <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateUserID"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateApplicationSource"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </EUID>
            <divisionNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber"/>
            </divisionNumber>
            <storeNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber"/>
            </storeNumber>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="cust:CommunicationProfile[@cust:DirtyFlag='Y']">
        <xsl:for-each select="cust:UpdateTrackingInformation">
            <EUID>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="cust:UpdateUserID != '' ">
                        <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateUserID"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateApplicationSource"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </EUID>
            <divisionNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber"/>
            </divisionNumber>
            <storeNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber"/>
            </storeNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateTrackingInformation/cust:UpdateApplicationSource"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="cust:CommunicationProfile/cust:CommunicationProfilePreference[@cust:DirtyFlag='Y']">
        <xsl:for-each select="cust:UpdateTrackingInformation">
            <EUID>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="cust:UpdateUserID != '' ">
                        <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateUserID"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateApplicationSource"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </EUID>
            <divisionNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber"/>
            </divisionNumber>`enter code here`
            <storeNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber"/>
            </storeNumber>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</HeaderInformation>
```

Input XML:

```
    <cust:CommunicationProfile cust:CommunicationForm="address" cust:PrimaryFlag="Y" cust:DeletedFlag="Y" cust:DirtyFlag="N">
        <cust:UpdateTrackingInformation>
            <UpdateApplicationSource>ehh</cust:UpdateApplicationSource>
            <cust:UpdateUserID>user123</cust:UpdateUserID>
            <cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber>056</cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber>
            <cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber>100</cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber>
        </cust:UpdateTrackingInformation>
    <cust:CommunicationProfilePreference cust:DeletedFlag="N" cust:DirtyFlag="N">
        <cust:UpdateTrackingInformation>
            <cust:UpdateApplicationSource>kpf</cust:UpdateApplicationSource>
            <cust:UpdateUserID>user234</cust:UpdateUserID>
            <cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber>105</cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber>
            <cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber>811</cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber>
        </cust:UpdateTrackingInformation>
    </cust:CommunicationProfilePreference>
    <cust:CommunicationProfilePreference cust:DeletedFlag="Y" cust:DirtyFlag="Y">
        <cust:UpdateTrackingInformation>
            <cust:UpdateApplicationSource>cambusblitz</cust:UpdateApplicationSource>
            <cust:UpdateUserID>user345</cust:UpdateUserID>
            <cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber>888</cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber>
            <cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber>889</cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber>
        </cust:UpdateTrackingInformation>
    </cust:CommunicationProfilePreference>
    <cust:CommunicationProfilePreference cust:DeletedFlag="N" cust:DirtyFlag="Y">
        <cust:UpdateTrackingInformation>
           <cust:UpdateApplicationSource>mobile</cust:UpdateApplicationSource>
           <cust:UpdateUserID>user456</cust:UpdateUserID>
           <cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber>777</cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber>
           <cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber>778</cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber>
        </cust:UpdateTrackingInformation>
    </cust:CommunicationProfilePreference>
</cust:CommunicationProfile>
```

Comment: Question is not really clear, why not add sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think in terms of loops, when working in XSLT. Think nonprocedurally. Write an expression that will match only what you want to match. If it should match only the first it encounters, add the predicate `[1]` to the expression

Answer (score 1):

xsl:for-each is a mapping expression, not a loop. It's not guaranteed to process the items one at a time in order, so if you stopped processing it would be undefined which items had been processed and which had not.

In XSLT 2.0, you need to use recursion to achieve the desired effect. In XSLT 3.0, you can use xsl:iterate.

Answer (score 0):

@keshlam is right, bit if you must "break," write a recursive loop, then don't make the call when it's time to break.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "break" out of a `for-each` in XSLT, instead you have to make sure the expression only selects the right subset of nodes in the first place. If you wanted to process all children up to and including the first one that has DirtyFlag='Y' then you would restrict the select with a predicate

```
<xsl:for-each select="whatever[not(preceding-sibling::*[@cust:DirtyFlag='Y'])]">
```

This filters the set to exclude anything following the first dirty flag.

Comment: I have 1 DirtyFlag at Parent Level, multiple DirtyFlags at Child-Level and multiple DirtyFlags at GrandChild level.  I want to stop processing as soon as i find the first DirtyFlag="Y"

Comment: @saura123 I'll echo the comment on the question - please edit it to show a sample of your input and required output and we might be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: <cust:CommunicationProfile cust:CommunicationForm="email" cust:DirtyFlag="Y">

Comment: <cust:UpdateTrackingInformation>
     <cust:SourceSystemUpdateDate>2011-11-14T09:30:47Z</cust:SourceSystemUpdateDate>
     <cust:UpdateSourceSystem>banner</cust:UpdateSourceSystem>
     <cust:UpdateApplicationSource>bannersite</cust:UpdateApplicationSource>
     <cust:UpdateUserID></cust:UpdateUserID>
     <cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber>111</cust:UpdateEmployeeDivisionNumber>
     <cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber>112</cust:UpdateEmployeeFacilityNumber>
    </cust:UpdateTrackingInformation>

Comment: The above mentioned CommunicationProfile is Child level, at grandchildren level I have CommunicationProfilePreference, which has the same set of UpdateTrackingInformation.  UpdateTrackingInformation has a single occurrence at main Contact(Parent) Level, multiple occurrence at CommunicationProfile (Child) level, and multiple occurrence at CommunicationProfilePreference (Grandchildren) level. So, the tree is Contact--multiple profiles--multiple preference of each profile.  Output xml can have only one set of these UpdateTrackingInformation elements, whichever has DirtyFlag="Y"

Comment: <sourceApplicationName>
   <xsl:for-each select="cust:DataArea/cust:CustomerMaster">
     <xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="cust:ProcessingInformation[@cust:DirtyFlag='Y']">
    <xsl:value-of select="cust:UpdateTrackingInformation/cust:UpdateApplicationSource"/>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="cust:CommunicationProfile[not(preceding-sibling::*[@cust:DirtyFlag='Y'])][1]">
  <xsl:value-of select="cust:CommunicationProfile/cust:UpdateTrackingInformation/cust:UpdateApplicationSource"/>
      </xsl:when>

Comment: <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="cust:CommunicationProfile/cust:CommunicationProfilePreference[not(preceding-sibling::*[@cust:DirtyFlag='Y'])][1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="cust:CommunicationProfile/cust:CommunicationProfilePreference/cust:UpdateTrackingInformation/cust:UpdateApplicationSource"/>
       </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:for-each>
</sourceApplicationName>

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time putting question here, so I don't know how can I put in right format.  This is what i was trying to do in XSLT for one of the element.  I am first checking at the main parent level if dirty flag is Y, if that's met then i just need to get these elements from the parent level then I don't need to loop into multiple children and grand children.  I hope this might clarify my question and problem.

Comment: @saura123 rather than adding code in comments, you should use the "edit" link under the original question and add the additional detail to the question itself.  Comments have very limited formatting options.